# ImportError: No module named pytz, even though sys.path says it's there

Tags: python, pandas, pytz

Trying to use pandas with Python 2.7.6 and it can't seem to load the pytz module. Here's everything I have leading up to this error:

```
Matts-MacBook-Pro-2:~ mattrosenthal$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

Matts-MacBook-Pro-2:~ mattrosenthal$ python
Python 2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.version
2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]

>>> print sys.path
#(added newlines for readability)
['',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython-0.20.1-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-1.5-py2.7.egg', 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-3.5.1-py2.7.egg', 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg', 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pytz-2015.7-py2.7.egg', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages', 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

As you can see, `'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pytz-2015.7-py2.7.egg'` is definitely there in the sys path. However, when I try to import it:

```
>>> import pytz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pytz
```

This is what I believe to be the root cause of the main issue I'm trying to solve, which is that pandas won't import correctly on account of pytz not loading:

```
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    "extensions first.".format(module))
ImportError: C extension: No module named pytz.tzinfo not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.
```

If it helps, here's my current PATH variable:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

I'm completely mystified and I would appreciate any help! I have tried using pip, easy_install and even manually placing the pytz .egg file in the site-packages directory with none of them seeming to work.

Edit: Here's the output of `python -v -c "import pytz"`

```
# installing zipimport hook
import zipimport # builtin
# installed zipimport hook
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py
import site # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py
import os # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.pyc
import errno # builtin
import posix # builtin
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py
import posixpath # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/stat.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/stat.py
import stat # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/stat.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py
import genericpath # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/warnings.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/warnings.py
import warnings # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/warnings.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/linecache.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/linecache.py
import linecache # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/linecache.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/types.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/types.py
import types # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/types.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py
import UserDict # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py
import _abcoll # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/abc.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/abc.py
import abc # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/abc.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.py
import _weakrefset # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.pyc
import _weakref # builtin
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py
import copy_reg # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/traceback.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/traceback.py
import traceback # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/traceback.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py
import sysconfig # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py
import re # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py
import sre_compile # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.pyc
import _sre # builtin
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py
import sre_parse # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py
import sre_constants # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.py
import _sysconfigdata # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_osx_support.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_osx_support.py
import _osx_support # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_osx_support.pyc
# zipimport: found 135 names in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-3.5.1-py2.7.egg
import encodings # directory /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py
import encodings # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/codecs.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/codecs.py
import codecs # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/codecs.pyc
import _codecs # builtin
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.py
import encodings.aliases # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py
import encodings.utf_8 # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc
Python 2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pytz
# clear __builtin__._
# clear sys.path
# clear sys.argv
# clear sys.ps1
# clear sys.ps2
# clear sys.exitfunc
# clear sys.exc_type
# clear sys.exc_value
# clear sys.exc_traceback
# clear sys.last_type
# clear sys.last_value
# clear sys.last_traceback
# clear sys.path_hooks
# clear sys.path_importer_cache
# clear sys.meta_path
# clear sys.flags
# clear sys.float_info
# restore sys.stdin
# restore sys.stdout
# restore sys.stderr
# cleanup __main__
# cleanup[1] encodings
# cleanup[1] site
# cleanup[1] sysconfig
# cleanup[1] abc
# cleanup[1] _weakrefset
# cleanup[1] sre_constants
# cleanup[1] _codecs
# cleanup[1] _warnings
# cleanup[1] zipimport
# cleanup[1] _sysconfigdata
# cleanup[1] encodings.utf_8
# cleanup[1] _osx_support
# cleanup[1] codecs
# cleanup[1] signal
# cleanup[1] traceback
# cleanup[1] posix
# cleanup[1] encodings.aliases
# cleanup[1] exceptions
# cleanup[1] _weakref
# cleanup[1] re
# cleanup[1] sre_compile
# cleanup[1] _sre
# cleanup[1] sre_parse
# cleanup[2] copy_reg
# cleanup[2] posixpath
# cleanup[2] errno
# cleanup[2] _abcoll
# cleanup[2] types
# cleanup[2] genericpath
# cleanup[2] stat
# cleanup[2] warnings
# cleanup[2] UserDict
# cleanup[2] os.path
# cleanup[2] linecache
# cleanup[2] os
# cleanup sys
# cleanup __builtin__
# cleanup ints: 827 unfreed ints
# cleanup floats
```

Comment: **you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first**

Comment: Please run `python -v -c "import pytz"` and show the output

Comment: It's pretty long, see edited post

Comment: @rbp I tried that but I get `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: try to `imp.load_module` from the file explicitly to see if the package is usable.

Comment: Have you tried (manually) removing the egg file and any pytz directories in `site-packages` (so that everything `pytz` is gone, and then re-installing pytz? Also, make sure if you do a manual uninstall/removal, that both `/Library/Python/...` and `/Library/Frameworks/...` don't contain `pytz` before reinstallation.

Comment: @Evert IT WORKS!! I removed the .egg file from /Library/Python and then did a reinstall with sudo easy_install pytz and now it works! Thanks so much for the suggestion

Comment: You're welcome. (Software) power cycle: standard course of action.